# CIFilter blurry on CALayer on Retina display

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, core-image

If I add a CIFilter to a CALayer like this...

```
filteredLayer.filters = @[filter];
```

...the filter works fine on a normal display. However, the same code running on a Retina display applies the filter, but the image is blurry.

If I don't apply the filter, the layer renders at the correct resolution.

I don't think the blurriness is necessarily a 1x/2x issue – it appears clearer than 1x would look but blurrier than 2x.

The contentsScale attribute seems to be set correctly (it's 2).

This is on OS X Mavericks, and the same thing happens on the Yosemite beta.

Comment: could you provide two screenshots? How is the filter created?